# PDFBox character bad characters in the pdf to string conversation

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox 1.8.4 to convert PDF to string.
For example my pdf contains : Pólya, G. and G. Szegő,
The output is : Po´lya, G. and G. Szego˝

Is there any way to solve that problem? (Yeah i know i can change with replaceAll("o'","ó"))

```
   PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(path);
   PDFTextStripper strp = new PDFTextStripper("UTF-8");
   System.out.println(strp.getText(doc));
```

All suggestions are welcomed!

Edit 1:
[PDF_Example](http://ac.inf.elte.hu/Vol_037_2012/157_37.pdf)

Comment: Please show the PDF in question. This may be a shortcoming of PDFBox, but it may also be an issue of the PDF.

Comment: Hi. I added it to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document presented by the OP contains e.g. this line

[image: Attila Gobi, Zalan Sz}ugyi and Tamas Kozsik]

which quite likely is a sample of the issue he has identified.

Looking at the page content stream, though,

```
[(A)32(ttila)-384(G\023)575(obi,)-383
(Zal)8(\023)567(an)-383(Sz)-32(})607(ugyi)-384(and)-383
(T)96(am)8(\023)567(as)-384(Kozsik)]TJ
```

one sees that e.g. in `(G\023)575(obi,)` **ó** is created by first drawing the **´** (*\023*), then going back the width of that glyph (575), and then drawing the **o**.

Thus, you do have these two glyphs **´** and **o** printed in the same location, not a single glyph **ó**.

PDFBox `PDFTextStripper` currently does not combine characters printed at the same location other than dropping the identical glyph drawn twice at about the same location.

Thus aside from *replaceAll("o'","ó")* as mentioned by the OP, one can also extend the `PDFTextStripper` to combine certain glyphs, either early in its method `processTextPosition` or late in `writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions)`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is with the PDF file encoding (i.e. the encoding is not `UTF-8`).

As a hint look at [this question](http://pdfbox.apache.org/userguide/faq.html#gibberish) on [PDFBox docuemntaion FAQ](http://pdfbox.apache.org/userguide/faq.html).